# How to use laravel Crypter class in blade template

Tags: security, laravel, laravel-4

I use this code from the laravel docs but i received this error
"Class 'Crypter' not found"
I had set the 32 character in app.php

```
Crypter::encrypt('I actually like Hello Kitty');
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're using the wrong class name, try:

```
Crypt::encrypt('I actually like Hello Kitty');
```